# Using the namespace, http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/ causes an error

Tags: jpa

I changed the title (Unable to load Persistence Unit from EAR) because i think the problem is, i can't use "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" url. instead, i have to use "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" url.

When i use "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence", i get these errors:

```
SEVERE: Unable to load Persistence Unit from EAR: F:\Web Design\wwwroot\Ali Farvardin\Farvardin Workshop\Workshop\build\web, module: file:/F:/Web%20Design/wwwroot/Ali%20Farvardin/Farvardin%20Workshop/Workshop/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/. Exception: unexpected element (uri:"http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence", local:"persistence"). Expected elements are <{http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence}persistence>
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence", local:"persistence"). Expected elements are <{http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence}persistence>
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:662)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:258)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:253)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:120)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1063)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:498)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:480)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:150)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.startElement(XMLFilterImpl.java:551)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:379)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3138)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:880)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.parse(XMLFilterImpl.java:357)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:258)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:229)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
    at org.apache.openejb.jee.jpa.unit.JaxbPersistenceFactory.getPersistence(JaxbPersistenceFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ReadDescriptors.deploy(ReadDescriptors.java:176)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory$Chain.deploy(ConfigurationFactory.java:401)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureApplication(ConfigurationFactory.java:962)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1214)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1087)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5378)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:672)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:547)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1671)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1485)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:882)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:368)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It's referred to my persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd" version="2.1">
  <persistence-unit name="WorkshopPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:global/jdbc/FarvardinWorkshop</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And this is the DD file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/login.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <description>Farvardin Workshop</description>
    <resource-env-ref>
        <description>DB Connection</description>
        <resource-env-ref-name>jdbc/FarvardinWorkshop</resource-env-ref-name>
        <resource-env-ref-type>javax.sql.DataSource</resource-env-ref-type>
    </resource-env-ref>

    <context-param>
       <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
       <param-value>none</param-value>
     </context-param>      

</web-app>
```

And context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/Workshop">
    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" name="jdbc/FarvardinWorkshop" password="don't look, it's a secret" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/FarvardinWorkshop" username="root"/>
</Context>
```

**Specification:**

Web Server: Apache TomEE Web Profile 1.7.0

Framework: JSF

Libraries: PrimeFaces 5.0, Eclipselink 2.5, Myfaces 2.2.4

Platform : JDK 1.8

IDE: Netbeans 8.0

=========================================

Considering deprecation of "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence", What is my mistake?

Grateful in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TomEE currently supports only JavaEE 6, while eclipselink 2.5 is JPA 2.1 and thus JavaEE 7.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_EE_version_history

if you want to use eclipselink with tomee you should use 2.4.2 (as packaged with the PluME version) for now.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Jan. You mean, i can't use "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" for now?

Comment: no with current version of TomEE, you can use it once the EE 7 compatible one is out.

Answer (score 1):

had the same problem, change  hibernate to a old version  (for example 4.1.4 final), apparently to recent versions of JPA 2.1 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

I found the error. It is the persistence version, we are using 2.1 and Tomee does not support it. Thus, go to persistence.xml and remove the following code

`<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">`

and add this

`xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">`

It works :)